# Making a simple clicker program in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get into coding a bit. The program I am working on now wants me to click a button on my screen, so I am making a simple clicker code. I tried using `pyautogui` to just click a button, so that I can eventually search for an image on the screen.

My code is:

```
import pyautogui
click(1,1079)
```

That's it. It is saved as a .py file, but when I run it it doesn't do anything. Any ideas to make it work?

Comment: The first thing about getting into coding is that *you* have to do it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks) is quite clear about what you need to do.

Comment: Aren't you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you installed pyautogui correctly it would work like this:

```
import pyautogui as gui
gui.click(1,1079)
```

The issue you had was that you import pyautogui but don't reference the module in the call of the method of the module.

Giving the module a name (I called it gui) is optional. If you don't want to do so you should use:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(1,1079)
```

Another way to do so is to import the method itself

```
from pyautogui import click
click(1,1079)
```

If you want to import ALL methods of the module you can use:

```
from pyautogui import *
click(1,1079)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the solution mentioned by HibertB, It's not necessary to have a reference unless your code complexity depends on multiple functions utilizes the same library.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(1,1079)
```

would be sufficient. In your question, you probably missed the '.' operator.